# Oracle: Exclude Results From Query Using a Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Using linq  (.net 3.5 +) and [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), I did it like so:

```
var startsWith3Chars = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]{3}\-", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
wherePredicate = wherePredicate.And(x => startsWith3Chars.Matches(x.MATERIALUID).Count > 0);
```

But now I have the need to do this filtering within the command text.

Is there a way to use something like REGEXP_INSTR to limit the results based on a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this test data ...

```
SQL> select name
  2  from t23
  3  /

NAME
----------
SAM-I-AM
MR KNOX
X11
CAT
LORAX

SQL>
```

... the following query uses REGEXP_LIKE() to return records whose first four characters contain only letters or hyphens:

```
SQL> select name
  2  from t23
  3  where regexp_like(name, '^[[:alpha:]\-]{4}')
  4  /

NAME
----------
SAM-I-AM
LORAX

SQL>
```

We can also use REGEXP_INSTR() with the same basic pattern (I have dropped the leading caret):

```
SQL> select name
  2  from t23
  3  where regexp_instr(name, '[[:alpha:]\-]{4}', 1) = 1
  4  /

NAME
----------
SAM-I-AM
LORAX

SQL>
```

Oracle added full regular expression support to its SQL in version 10g.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately working with an older version of Oracle. Thanks though, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about [REGEXP_LIKE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#BABGDGIH)?

Comment: APC sort of 1 up-ed you with an example. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Not a problem - if APC has the time to provide the example, then the credit should go there. If you would have needed the info in a hurry then what I provided would have got you there. It's all about solutions, not scoring.